# People keep recieving facetime calls from my phone but I have not called them, Also when when they answer it is a different person. what has happened?

Tags: iphone, facetime

I have received texts from people saying they have missed facetime calls from me when I have not called them. Also, today y girlfriend received a facetime call from me and when the call connected there was a woman staring back at her. She immediately hung up and when it called back she ignored it. It says on her call log that it was me who facetimed her. how could this have happened?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me your apple id is compromised and someone else is using it.
Though I don't know why they'd call people in your contacts list.
I'd suggest resetting your password ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.  I received a random call from a guy claiming my phone keeps calling him on facetime.  My phone was on my desk no where near anything that could initiate a call and I do not have this guy's number in my phone or ipad.  I also checked the call history and his number wasn't there.  I changed my appleid password so hopefully this puts a stop to it.  Kind of creepy!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.